# Is this proof on difference between powers of prime roots of $-1$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let's say I have a polynomial $P(x) $with $n$ distinct roots $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$,$\alpha_3$ ,$\dots$, $\alpha_n$ where $P(x)$ is:

$$ P(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots (x-\alpha_{i})\dots(x-\alpha_n)$$

Then one can easily show the RHS will have $n-1$ coefficients with the exception of $ (x-\alpha_i)$ for:

$${P'(\alpha_i)} = (\alpha_i - \alpha_1)(\alpha_i - \alpha_2)\dots(\alpha_i - \alpha_n) $$

Or:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n P'(\alpha_i) = \prod_{i \neq j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)$$

Now, we constraint $P(x)$ and extend it's definition it as follows:

$$ P(x,i,j) = \frac{(x^{p_i}+1)(x^{p_j}+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$

where $p_i$ and $p_j$ are primes $p_i \neq 2 \neq p_j$

The roots of the above equation are integer powers of $\omega_{p_i} = e^{i \pi /p_i} $ and $\omega_{p_j} = e^{i \pi /p_j} $. One can use the above and define:

$$ A = \prod_r^{p_i +1} P'(\omega_{p_i}^r,i,j) = p_i \frac{\omega_{p_i}^{p_i - 1}(\omega_{p_i}^{p_j} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_i}  +1 )^2} \cdot  p_i \frac{\omega_{p_i}^{2(p_i - 1)}(\omega_{p_i}^{2p_j} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_i}^2  +1 )^2} \cdots p_i \frac{\omega_{p_i}^{(p_i - 1)^2}(\omega_{p_i}^{(p_i+1)p_j} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_i}^{p_i+1}  +1 )^2} $$

$$ B = \prod_r^{p_j +1} P'(\omega_{p_j}^r,i,j) = p_j \frac{\omega_{p_j}^{p_j - 1}(\omega_{p_j}^{p_i} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_j}  +1 )^2} \cdot  p_j \frac{\omega_{p_j}^{2(p_j - 1)}(\omega_{p_j}^{2p_i} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_j}^2  +1 )^2} \cdots p_j \frac{\omega_{p_j}^{(p_j - 1)^2}(\omega_{p_j}^{(p_j+1)p_i} + 1)}{ (\omega_{p_j}^{p_j+1}  +1 )^2} $$

Simplifying the above:

$$ A = p_i^{p_i+1}  \frac{\omega_{p_i}^{(p_i - 1)^2 p_i/2}\prod_r^{p_i+1} (\omega_{p_i}^{r p_j} + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_i+1} (\omega_{p_i}^r  +1 )^2} $$

$$ B = p_j^{p_j+1}  \frac{\omega_{p_j}^{(p_j - 1)^2 p_j/2}\prod_r^{p_j+1} (\omega_{p_j}^{r p_i} + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_j+1} (\omega_{p_j}^r  +1 )^2} $$

Using modular arithmetic and $\omega_{p_i}^{p_i} = -1$:

$$ A = (-1)^{(p_i - 1)^2 /2} p_i^{p_i-1}  \frac{\prod_r^{p_i-1} (\omega_{p_i}^{r} + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_i-1} (\omega_{p_i}^r  +1 )^2}  $$

$$B =  (-1)^{(p_j - 1)^2 /2} p_j^{p_j-1}  \frac{\prod_r^{p_j-1} (\omega_{p_j}^{r } + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_j-1} (\omega_{p_j}^r  +1 )^2}$$

Hence,

$$ \prod_{l \neq k} (C_l - C_k) = AB =(-1)^{\frac{(p_i - 1)^2 +(p_j -1)^2}{2}} p_i^{p_i-1} p_j^{p_j-1}  \frac{\prod_r^{p_i-1} (\omega_{p_i}^{r} + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_i-1} (\omega_{p_i}^r  +1 )^2} \frac{\prod_r^{p_j-1} (\omega_{p_j}^{r } + 1)}{\prod_r^{p_j-1} (\omega_{p_j}^r  +1 )^2}  $$

And $C_{i}$ is any member of the set $(\omega_{p_i}, \omega_{p_i}^2, \omega_{p_i}^3,\dots, \omega_{p_i}^{p_i-1},\omega_{p_j}, \omega_{p_j}^2, \omega_{p_j}^3,\dots, \omega_{p_j}^{p_j-1})$

### Question

Is the above proof correct? If not which step is wrong? Can this be simplified further? P.S: I wish I could cross check it with a simple example but even the example is too long for wolframalpha

Comment: I'm not sure if this is essential, but the function $P(x,i,j)=\frac{(x^{p_i}+1)(x^{p_j}+1)}{(x-1)^2}$ isn't a polynomial in $x$. Also, what did you get as your value for $P'(x,i,j)$. It looks like you just differentiated the $x^{p_i}+1$ term and treated everything else as constant. You need to apply quotient rule.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Doesn't the $(x-1)^2$ in the denominator cancel? Since $-1$ is a root of both $(1+x^{p_i})$ and $(1+x^{p_j})$. I did apply the quotient rule the other terms go to $0$ since I insert $\omega_{p_i}$ in them

Comment: @MoreAnonymous $\,P(x,i,j)\,$ is not a polynomial, though it would be one if you changed the denominator to $\,(x+1)^2\,$. About "*the roots of the above equation are integer powers of...*" $\;-\;$ yes, but not just any integer powers, they are all *odd* powers of $\,\omega_p\,$. The even powers $\omega_p^{2k}$ are not roots of $\,x^p+1\,$ (but instead of $\,x^p-1\,$).

Comment: @dxiv thanks .. .Silly me

Comment: It looks like you corrected the fact that $P(x,i,j)$ wasn't a polynomial, but I still don't think your derivative is right. What did you get for the value of $P'(x,i,j)$?